# Error while running the android studio

Tags: android

how to fix android studio run time issue failed to capture snapshots of output files fortask 'transform classeswithDexForDebug' property 'streamoutputfolder' during updodate checkup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - transform Classes With Dex For Debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237253/android-transform-classes-with-dex-for-debug)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065324/failed-to-capture-snapshot-of-output-files-for-task)

Comment: refer this  [StackOverFlow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237253/android-transform-classes-with-dex-for-debug#answer-39268997)

Answer (score 0):

check your build.gradle file has following code.

```
android{
    defaultConfig {

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }


    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
dependencies {
    //...
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**enable multidex as following:**

```
android {    
defaultConfig {
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
 }  
}
 dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

**create one class like this**

```
public class Multi_Dex extends Application {
 @Override
 protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
 }
}
```

**now in your manifiest file add this**

```
<application
    android:name=".Multi_Dex"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```